# Windows Authentication In Angular 2 Application and ASP.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, angular2-services

I'm trying to implement Windows authentication for my Angular 4 application which is accessing an ASP.Net Web API for all its data needs. I have a controller in my Web API named `AuthenticationController` with a method named `Authenticate` that returns the Domain\Username if the authentication is successful.
The code for the `AuthenticationController` is as follows:

```
namespace MyAppWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public LoginModels Authenticate()
        {
            Debug.Write($"AuthenticationType: {User.Identity.AuthenticationType}");
            Debug.Write($"IsAuthenticated: {User.Identity.IsAuthenticated}");
            Debug.Write($"Name: {User.Identity.Name}");

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //return Ok($"Authenticated: {User.Identity.Name}");
                return new LoginModels { DomainName = User.Identity.Name, Role = "Admin" };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception ("Not authenticated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `LoginModels` is a model as follows:

```
public class LoginModels
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

I have enabled CORS in my `WebApiConfig.cs` under AppStart folder and the code for that is as follows:

```
namespace MyAppWebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            //Resolve CORS Issue
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://MyAngularApplicationIP:port", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have enabled Windows authentication in my `Web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Now in my Angular Application I have a service named `AuthenticationHelperService` as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationHelperService {

    constructor(
        private _httpHelperService: HttpHelperService,
        private _http: Http,
        private _requestOptions: RequestOptions,
    ) { }

    public authenticateUser(): Observable<any> {
        console.log('Calling GetUser');
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
        return this._http
            .get('WebApiURL:port/api/Authentication/Authenticate', options)
            .map(this._httpHelperService.extractData)
            .catch(this._httpHelperService.handleError);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have enabled the `withCredentials: true` in the request option. Also, here `_httpHelperService.extractData` simply converts my response into JSON and `_httpHelperService.handleError` logs the error (if any) on the console.
Now, I am calling this service method from a component on page load in a `ngOnInit` method as follows:

```
export class MasterComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private _userLoginService : UserLoginService,
        private _authenticationHelperService: AuthenticationHelperService
    ) { }

    private userName: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this._authenticationHelperService.authenticateUser().subscribe(
            data => this.userName = data,
            error => console.log('Authentication Error :: ' + error),
            () => console.log('Current User :: ' + this.userName));
    }
}
```

When I run the application then the browser asks me to enter the credentials -
[Please See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXMzQ.jpg)
After entering the credentials it takes me to the homepage but the `_authenticationHelperService.authenticateUser()` method doesn't return the Username. I am getting an error on the console as follows:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "MyWebApiURL/api/Authentication/Authenticate". Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "MyAngularAppUrl" is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

When I simply call the Authenticate method of the Web API from the browser like `http://MyWebApiIP:port/api/Authentication/Authenticate` then I get my Username successfully but not from the Angular Application.

Comment: The CORS preflight request is not working it should return a HTTP 200 but instead is receiving a 401 see if this sample helps to understand how to configure CORS in your Web API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? If so what was the solution?

Comment: @BenCameron I followed this tutorial: https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angularjs-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/ and everything is working peachy.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to

WindowsAuthentication

you also need to enable

AnonymousAuthentication

since the OPTIONS Pre-flight request does not carry Auth headers, and will fail if it's not enabled.

just remember to [Authorize] all of your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

launchSettings.json

you can find this file in your project in property folder,

```html
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53072/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AdvantureWeb": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    }
  }
}
```

change to window authentication